# Convert from/to gitlab flavored markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Usually, I convert from/to markdown with pandoc, but unfortunately, pandoc does not support gitlab flavored markdown.

What is a good approach to convert it from/to any pandoc supported formats like pandoc's markdown, github flavored markdown, etc. ?

Comment: let me add this short rant: Nearly every time I ask a question, about how to use a tool, or to convert to a tool specific language, or otherwise mention a tool prominently, there is at least one close vote because "I see recommendation for a tool"...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to tweak pandoc, most importantly [filters](https://pandoc.org/filters.html). This allows to support the features and custom extensions of GitLab Flavored Markdown, but it has to be done "by hand".

The important parts are:

- support for Mermaid diagrams,
- support for PlantUML diagrams, and
- interpretation of special code blocks as math formulæ.

All of these can be done with filters, given that the necessary diagram programs are installed.

One such approach is described here: https://gist.github.com/MyriaCore/75729707404cba1c0de89cc03b7a6adf